# PHP OOP accessing global variable

Tags: php

I have two php files. The first is for the library and the other is for the function the       problem is if I declare the variable outside the class then I get an error saying unidentified variable. Need help thanks in advance.

**lib.php**

```
class test{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_link = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
        mysql_select_db('test_db', $this->_link);
    }
    public function query($sql)
    {

    }
}
```

**Function.php**

```
include_once('lib.php');
$lib = new test();

function testFunction(){
    $lib->query($sql);
}
```

The problem is the variable `$db` is unidentified and I don't want to type `$lib = new test()` for every function. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You really need to indent your code properly. Mixing tabs and spaces is a really bad idea. Additionally your code contains syntax error, e.g. the class name is missing in the `class` definition. Please do not post code containing syntax errors here!

Comment: `mysql_*` is now **deprecated**. Please look into either *PDO* or *mysqli*.

Comment: if you're doing OOP properly, you shouldn't need any global variables.

Comment: Sorry sir the name of the class is test I forgot to put it XD. How do I call the variable $db = new test() so that the functions will recognize it.

Comment: pass `$lib` into your test function `function testFunction($lib)`

Comment: That is called [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection). [This video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RlfLCWKxHJ0) can help you to understand.

Answer (score 2):

Access the variable from inside every function using

```
function whatever($bar) {
    global $lib;
    $lib->foo($bar);
```

or pass $lib as a parameter

```
function whatever($lib, $bar) {
    $lib->foo($bar);
```

Answer (score 0):

Function.php

```
include_once('lib.php');
$lib = new test();

function testFunction()
{
    global $lib;
    $lib->query($sql);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [`global`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.global) keyword to mark the variable as global.

This should be used sparingly as excessive use of globals is indicative of bad program design.